# biased coin flip. expected sequence

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

A biased coin $C$ has $\Pr(H) = a$ and $\Pr(T) = 1-a$. The coin $C$ is flipped $n$ times.
What is the expected number of times that the consecutive sequence $HXH$ occurs where $X$
can be either $H$ or $T$?

---

This would be easy if the $HXH$ did not contain the $X$ variable.

This is my attempt:
$(n-2)[a^3 \cup (a^2)(1-a)]$

OK so would it be $(n-2)[a^3+a^2(1-a)]$ instead?

Comment: One approach could be to calculate the expected number of HHH and the expected number of HTH, and then add them. Since no 3-sequence can be both at the same time, you should be done.

Comment: The expression $a^3\cup(a^2)(1-a)$ does not make sense.  One puts "$\cup$" between two _events_, not between two _numbers_.

Answer (score 1):

Partition the length n sequence into triples, calculate the probability of your given set of triples {HTH,HHH} among the set of all triples. This assumes overlapping triples are not counted twice, e.g. HTHTH gives one HTH triple, not two. To account for the overlap, eliminate the first element of the sequence, recalculate. Then eliminate the first two and recalculate. Add the three results.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the expected number of HXH's that occur is the sum of the expected number of HHH's and HTH's. There are $n-2$ triples to consider. Let $X_i$ be the indicator that the $i$th triple is HHH and let $Y_i$  be the indicator that the $i$th triple is HTH.

Then the expected value in question is $$E[\sum (X_i +Y_i)] = \sum E[X_i] + \sum E[Y_i] = (n-2) E[X_1] + (n-2)E[Y_1]$$
$$
=(n-2)P[X_1=1] + (n-2)P[Y_1=1]
$$
$$
= (n-2)a^3 + (n-2)a^2(1-a)
$$
$$
=(n-2)(a^3+a^2(1-a))
$$
as you suggested.